# Jenkins Error: No versions are present in the repository for the artifact with a range [1.4,) commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:null

Tags: jenkins, artifactory

I am using Maven version 2.2.1 and Artifactory 3.5.2.1.Jenkins build fails with error:

```
[INFO] Failed to resolve artifact.
No versions are present in the repository for the artifact with a range [1.4,)
  commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:null
from the specified remote repositories:
  central (http://myartifactory.com/PROJECT_REPO-virtual),
  snapshots (http://myartifactory.com/PROJECT_REPO-virtual)

Path to dependency: 
    1) org.codehaus.mojo:jasperreports-maven-plugin:maven-plugin:1.0-beta-2
    2) jasperreports:jasperreports:jar:1.2.0
```

I have added the project's nexus repository as remote repository in Artifactory but still build fails with above error.
The same build is successful if i add the project's nexus repository in the pom file.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Please show us your `pom.xml` and `settings.xml` files. Also, why are you using a version range for `commons-beanutils`...?

Comment: I got the same error in Bamboo and I updated the plan to use Maven 3 and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Version ranges don't work very well under Maven `2.x`. You should consider upgrading to Maven 3.3.x, or defining a concrete version for your dependency. Allowing silent upgrades to third-party dependencies without your approval can be dangerous and at the very least impact your build's stability.